# Get store data items value in sencha ext js

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, extjs-stores

I have this data in a JSON file.

```
{
    data: [
        {
            lari: 1.75
        }
    ]
}
```

I want get this lari's value e.g.:

```
var lari = mystore.data.items[0];
```

I'm using this code:

```
Ext.define('Currency.store.mystore',
    { extend: 'Ext.data.Store', requires: 
       [ 'Currency.model.MyModel', 'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax', 'Ext.data.reader.Json' ],
       constructor: function(cfg) {
          var me = this;
           cfg = cfg || {};
           me.callParent([Ext.apply({
               model: 'Currency.model.MyModel', storeId: 'mystore',
               proxy: { type: 'ajax', url: 'data.json',
                 reader: { type: 'json', root: 'data' 
...

Ext.encode(Ext.pluck(mystore.data.items[0], 'data'));
```

but I have an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: mystore is not defined
>   userclassname: 'mystore',

Please help me. How to write this code?

Answer (score 2):

Define the storeId of your store:

```
Ext.define('Currency.store.mystore', { 
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId: 'mystore',
    // ...
```

And find the first element:

```
var lari = Ext.getStore("mystore").getAt(0);
```

Comment: then your model is wrong, add the model definition to your question, so i can see it

Comment: I realized my problem. in onlaunch function I write 
var lari = Ext.getStore("mystore").proxy.reader.jsonData.data[0].lari;
and consol out: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined.
I thought this command start first and after load store. becouse when I wrote this command in consol "Ext.getStore("mystore").proxy.reader.jsonData.data[0].lari;" everythings working good. so what can I do.